# What is the best way to put name and job title on two separate lines on a webpage using HTML, CSS?

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to put my name and job title centered vertically and horizontally on a webpage for my own website. I want to have my name with Web Developer underneath it.

I used this method:

```
.landing{

height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

}
```

This works but doesnt take into account a `position:fixed border with height=60px` into account (it doesn't come out totally vertically centered).

Is there another way to centred these items regardless of additional elements on the page? (margin: auto also creates the same problem as above).

In addition, how should the html layout look, currently:

```
<div class="landing">
   <div class="landing1">HasanMirza</div>
   <div class="landing2">Web De<span class="v">v</span>eloper</div>
</div>
```

(the 'v' is rotated to look like an angle bracket, just an effect I am trying to achieve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to position anything in your viewport in a fixed position irrespective of any other element then use `position: fixed`. Grid allows you to place items in the center really easily. See code below:

- Info on positioning on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)
- How to center using grid [W3docs.com](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-center-the-content-in-grid.html)

```css
body {
  margin:0; /* the items will have an 8px offset if this isn't set to zero */
}

.landing {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
  <div class="landing1">HasanMirza</div>
  <div class="landing2">Web De<span class="v">v</span>eloper</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just added ```top: -60px``` and that the effect I wanted